# MAXDOP Settings When Exceeding the Recommendation

Tags: sql-server

I have an Sql Server 2014 Enterprise  running on VMWare with 32 logical processors assigned. Based on Microsoft recommendation the MAXDOP should be set to 8. However when I run a large query against multiple large tables:

With MAXDOP at 8:     7 Minutes
With MAXDOP at 16:    3 Minutes

My questions is what issue I could encounter if I to set the MAXDOP to 16 which is half the number of logical processors?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You say you have 32 logical processes, however, how many NUMA nodes do you have. Setting it to 8 is the recommendation for when you have greater than 8 logical processors and **one** NUMA node. I would guess you have more.

Comment: Thanks Larnu I checked the number of NUMA nodes by changing the graph in Windows Task Manager to NUMA Nodes and there is only one NUMA node

Answer (score 2):

"**it depends**" on your processor footprint and the NUMA configuration and  Below is a quick TSQL script to generate Recommendation for MAXDOP setting

```
   declare @hyperthreadingRatio bit
   declare @logicalCPUs int
   declare @HTEnabled int
   declare @physicalCPU int
   declare @SOCKET int
   declare @logicalCPUPerNuma int
   declare @NoOfNUMA int
   
   select @logicalCPUs = cpu_count -- [Logical CPU Count]
       ,@hyperthreadingRatio = hyperthread_ratio --  [Hyperthread Ratio]
       ,@physicalCPU = cpu_count / hyperthread_ratio -- [Physical CPU Count]
       ,@HTEnabled = case 
           when cpu_count > hyperthread_ratio
               then 1
           else 0
           end -- HTEnabled
   from sys.dm_os_sys_info
   option (recompile);
   
   select @logicalCPUPerNuma = COUNT(parent_node_id) -- [NumberOfLogicalProcessorsPerNuma]
   from sys.dm_os_schedulers
   where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
       and parent_node_id < 64
   group by parent_node_id
   option (recompile);
   
   select @NoOfNUMA = count(distinct parent_node_id)
   from sys.dm_os_schedulers -- find NO OF NUMA Nodes 
   where [status] = 'VISIBLE ONLINE'
       and parent_node_id < 64
   
   -- Report the recommendations ....
   select
       --- 8 or less processors and NO HT enabled
       case 
           when @logicalCPUs < 8
               and @HTEnabled = 0
               then 'MAXDOP setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUs as varchar(3))
                   --- 8 or more processors and NO HT enabled
           when @logicalCPUs >= 8
               and @HTEnabled = 0
               then 'MAXDOP setting should be : 8'
                   --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NO NUMA
           when @logicalCPUs >= 8
               and @HTEnabled = 1
               and @NoofNUMA = 1
               then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))
                   --- 8 or more processors and HT enabled and NUMA
           when @logicalCPUs >= 8
               and @HTEnabled = 1
               and @NoofNUMA > 1
               then 'MaxDop setting should be : ' + CAST(@logicalCPUPerNuma / @physicalCPU as varchar(3))l
           else ''
           end as Recommendations
```

## What can happen if i set MaxDop to 16

**Max degree of parallelism**,  if set to higher value, can perform better in running single query, which you already noticed. But setting higher maxdop will consume your sql server threads more quickly and you may be subject to **thread starvation** in production environment with heavy data load.
Please make sure to set **cost threshold for parallelism** which tells sql server to perform parallelism based on crossing the threshold value you have set to **cost threshold for parrallelism**